# How do i remove a node if a child node is a duplicate

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to transform an xml using xslt1.

Basically, I want to remove a node if a certain child's childnode already exists
the input has a format like:

```
<Quote>
  … lots of data … 
  <ItemService>
     <ID></ID>
      …
     <Product>
       <InternalId>value</InternalId>
       <DeliveryInfo>
           <lots of subitems>
       </Deliveryinfo>
       <service>SERVICETEYPE</service>
       <some more infos/>
     </Product>
     …
  </Itemservice>
  <ItemService>
     <ID></ID>
      …
     <Product>
       <InternalId>value</InternalId>
       <DeliveryInfo>
           <lots of subitems>
       </deliveryinfo>
       <service>SERVICETEYPE</service>
       <some more infos/>
    </Product>
     … 
  </ItemService>
 … some more data …
</quote>
```

So I want to remove the `<ItemService>` if another `<ItemService>` with the same value already exists.

Say we have 10 ItemServices where there are three where the Product/service value is 'assembly' I want only one (don't care which one) is left in the output.

I have tried so many things, yet it never adds up...

I think this goes in the right direction, bit it doesn't work...

Any help is greatly appreciated, xslt is not my cup of tea, and this one is really annoying me...

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="product" match="Product" use="concat(generate-id(parent::*), service)"/> 
        
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ItemService">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Product[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('product' , concat(generate-id(parent::*), service))[1])]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am guessing (!) correctly, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-service" match="ItemService" use="Product/service" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Quote">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::ItemService)]"/>
        <!-- keep only distinct items -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ItemService[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('item-by-service', Product/service)[1])]" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which could be reduced to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="item-by-service" match="ItemService" use="Product/service" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove duplicate items -->
<xsl:template match="ItemService[not(generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('item-by-service', Product/service)[1]))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**IMPORTANT:**

XML is case-sensitive: `Service` is not the same as `service` and `</product>` does not close `<Product>`.

Comment: i edited the question so the capitals match.
Everything that commes out of the ERP/CRM system Always has at least one capital in it. The data that gets added afterwards i never ad capitals to keep track of what commes from where.
Lots of thaks for your answer, really helped me out!